Problems configuring Azure App Service for React app
I have a React app, built with Vite and hosted on Azure App Service. I am having some issues regarding configuration:

Compression is not working, we have deployed gziped files, but they are never sent by the server, only the uncompressed files are
Wasm files are being served with the wrong Content-Type. The response has a content type of text/plain instead of application/wasm

I have added the following Web.config but it hasn't had any effect at all:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <httpCompression>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <clear />
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <clear />
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
</configuration>


@Gustao Shigueo please provide logstream of your app service.

can you provide your github repo ?

@Gustavo Shigueo you want to deploy you react dist folder in .gz file to azure web application? or or web app processes compressed file? how are you deploy your application?

@SirraSneha I can't provide either of those unfortunately. It's an enterprise app, so the repo is private and I don't have access to the Azure dashboard, so no logs either. The team decided to dockerize the app and added NGINX to the docker image to solve the problem

Below method worked for me to deploy a react app in gzip file to azure web app.

To run web app using compressed file, WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to 1 and it only supports .zip file.

I deployed my web app using GitHub Action
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - reactvite2sep

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
          
      - name: Zipping files in gzip
        run: tar --exclude='./output.tar.gz' -czf output.tar.gz ./*
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: output.tar.gz

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_xxxxxxxxxxx }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_xxxxxxxxxxx }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_xxxxxxxxxxx }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'reactvite2sep'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

OUTPUT:


